# Amcharts custom variable color

Tags: laravel, vue.js, charts, amcharts, amcharts4

I want a dynamic color on my chart. I use a imported css file with some identity colors.
Like this:

```
:root
{
    --brand-color: {{$color}};
}
```

I am using the AmChart World chart as visualisation but the a4mchart.color() does not like variables. How do I make sure that it does take in variables? here my code:

```
let style = getComputedStyle(document.body);
let brandColor = style.getPropertyValue('--brand-color');
const chartWorld = am4core.create(this.$refs.chartdiv, am4maps.MapChart);

polygonSeries.fill = am4core.color(brandColor);
```

And this is what it returns:

```
Color {_value: {
alpha: 1
alternative: Color
darkColor: Color
hex: "#000000"
lightColor: Color
rgb: Object
rgba: "rgb(0,0,0)"
_value: {r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 1}
__proto__: Object…}}
```

It didn't change anything but the BrandColor does return the right string when I log it: `"#A4A2A3"`

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my testing, `getPropertyValue` returns everything after the property name, including any whitespace, which causes the color to not get parsed correctly by AmCharts; your log is likely returning `" #A4A2A3"`. You'll want to call `trim` on the string beforehand:

```
polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template.fill = am4core.color(brandColor.trim());
```

Note that you need to set the `fill` on the series' mapPolygon template for it to apply to your map regions.